# How to open the Windows Startup folder in file explorer via bash?

Tags: windows, bash, scripting, git-bash, startup

Startup folder path: `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, I've tried:

```
echo "$APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

start "$APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

Although the echoed path is correct, the `start` command just opens a CMD window, does anyone know how to open the Startup folder in file explorer via bash?

P.S. I'm using Git Bash.

Comment: What effect would you exactly want to achieve? An why did you tag this question with _sh_? Finally, tag this question so that we can see, which bash implementation you are using.

Comment: @user1934428 I want to open the Windows Startup folder in git bash. I've replaced the `sh` tag with `git-bash`.

Comment: And with "to open", you mean "starting Windows Explorer to show the folder"? Or do you just want to list the content of this folder? Please update your question, so that we can see what you want.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, in the file explorer, very good point! I've updated my question.

Comment: I've never worked in Git Bash, but AFIK, `start` is an internal command and not an executable. So if you would do anything with `start`, you likely would have to wrap it into a call to `cmd`, i.e. `cmd /c start ....`.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks, I used to use `start` to open folders, but it's sometimes unreliable, I'll stick with the `explorer` command from now on.

Comment: You can use cygstart.

Comment: @Philippe Unfortunately, it's not available on git bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command does the job:

```sh
start '' "$APPDATA/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup"
```

Reference: [Can I use the "start" command with spaces in the path?](https://superuser.com/a/239572/1023031)